# How to select the next tag in Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to show the form below.

**HTML**

```
<p><input type ="button" id="comment16" 
     value="Comment"></p>

 <div class="form" style="display:none">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('[id^="comment"]').click(function(e) {

            var $thisClicked = $(this);
            $thisClicked.next('.form').show();   
            alert($thisClicked.attr('id')); 

        });
```

My script does not work  even though alert show the right id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code

```
$('[id^="comment"]').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next('.form').show(); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wfH3/)**

Comment: Thank  you,  so sorry, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="comment"]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('p').next('.form').show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery::next` finds siblings. Your form div is not a sibling of your input button; it is a sibling of the input button's parent `<p>`. You need to change your code to reference the sibling of the parent.

```
$('[id^="comment"]').click(function (e) {
  var $thisClicked = $(this);
  var $nextForm = $thisClicked.parent().next('.form');
  $nextForm.show();
});
```